# Use of the singleton pattern in apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, singleton

I have to use an external library in the mapPartition function of RDD and for this I must call it through its implementation of the singleton pattern, which I can not modify because the library is not mine

I am trying to use the functions of the library by partition but there is concurrency conflict since sometimes the execution is satisfactory but other times there are nullPointerException exceptions and I imagine that it is the concurrent access of this library by the different partitions. This is the way the library is called `Strategy.getStrategy` . How can I make this library run with the global configuration that I offer but independently in each partition without concurrent access to its internal processes?

```
private def executeStrategy(iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[(String,(MyState,Double))] = {
  val listBest = new util.ArrayList[State]
  Predicate.fuzzyValues = iter.toList

  for (i <- 0 until conf.runNumber) {
    Strategy.getStrategy.executeStrategy(conf.iterByRun, 1, conf.algorithm("algorithm").asInstanceOf[GeneratorType])
    listBest.addAll(Strategy.getStrategy.listBest)
  }

  val result = postMining(listBest)

  result.map(x => (x.getCode.toString, (MyState(x.getCode), x.getEvaluation.get(0).asInstanceOf[Double]))).iterator
}

def run(sparkSession: SparkSession, n: Int): Unit = {
  var data0 = conf.dataBase.repartition(n).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
  var listBest = new util.ArrayList[State]

  val data1 = data0.rdd.mapPartitions(executeStrategy).reduceByKey((x,y) => x)
}
```

I expect that this library executes, with the global configuration that I offer, the code `Strategy.getStrategy.executeStrategy (conf.iterByRun, 1, conf.algorithm("algorithm").asInstanceOf[GeneratorType])` by partition but without conflicts of concurrence

Comment: Are you testing this local or in a distributed cluster? - you may `coalesce` your data to the number of machines, this way there should only be one partition per JVM, thus there should no be concurrent access problems. However... you may lose a lot of performance, so after the `mapPartitions` you may `repartition` your data again.

Comment: Or you may limit the number of _cores_ per **Executor** to 1.